# Woocommerce orders not showing all after upgrading Wordpress 5.0.3

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Woocommerce orders are not showing all in orders page of the admin panel after upgrading WordPress to v5.0.3.
After a little debugging, the query sent are different between two versions.
It used to be:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'shop_order' AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'wc-pending' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'wc-processing' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'wc-on-hold' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'wc-completed' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'wc-cancelled' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'wc-refunded' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'wc-failed' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'wc-shipped' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'wc-approved'))  ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 20
```

before but in newer version is:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.post_type = 'shop_order' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'wc-shipped' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'wc-approved' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'future' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'draft' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'pending' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 20
```

I'm using WooCommerce v3.2.1

Comment: https://woocommerce.wordpress.com/2018/12/20/woocommerce-3-5-3-release-notes/

Comment: I cannot upgrade WC because there're so many things tied to current version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the new query is missing some statuses for the orders.

Since you can't update WooCommerce, you could go into the core file and perform the same changes as in the fix.

Look for this in `includes/admin/list-tables/class-wc-admin-list-table-orders.php`:

```
if ( ! isset( $query_vars['post_status'] ) ) {
```

And change it to:

```
if ( empty( $query_vars['post_status'] ) ) {
```

Because the default variables of WordPress has changed.

This is the commit in question: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/compare/3.5.2...3.5.3#diff-572cadf09364d3a4d4e8c20e061b21f5

And the release note is here: https://woocommerce.wordpress.com/2018/12/20/woocommerce-3-5-3-release-notes/

### Update

Since the file doesn't exist in `3.5.2`, you can perform the same change in `class-wc-admin-post-types.php` at `line 1635`:

```
if ( ! isset( $vars['post_status'] ) ) {
```

To:

```
if ( empty( $vars['post_status'] ) ) {
```

Comment: There's no such file in woocommerce.

Comment: It works like a charm. I found another solution fixing `/wp-admin/includes/post.php` but it wasn't perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it works - if ( empty( $vars['post_status'] ) ) {

in version WC 3.2.6 , now a can see ALL ORDERS in admin table

Comment: And it was file - class-wc-admin-post-types.php